# How can I turn off the 3G connection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, networking, app-widgets, 3g, 3.1-honeycomb

I'd like to be able to turn the 3G connection on and off without navigating the "Settings -> Wireless and networks -> Mobile Networks" menus each time.

Is there a widget (or some other way) of turning 3G on and off from the home screen or the "Dashboard"?

Comment: Dashboard: I don't know what it is called but it is accessible by tapping the clock (bottom right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of widget use apps like [data switch](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tomatox.dataswitch). Unlike widget this app doesn't consume resource when idle. There are tons of other apps/widget if you don't like this one or this one doesn't work for you. For eg:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aispl.mdsswitch

https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.chernish2

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.m039.tools

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.myreallife.mobiledata

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.datalinkswitch

Answer (score 4):

I use the Power Control Widget. Allows you to toggle Data, wifi and various other settings from your home screen.